# Adding a view above UINavigationBar

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add a custom view above the navigation bar as displayed on the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5JNx.png) .

- What I've tried so far is to add the view as a subview of the navigation bar - Did not work
- Add the custom view first on Interface builder and then add a navigation bar manually - This seems to mess up with my navigation as the default navigation controller has it's own navigation bar.

Is this a bad approach on its own ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a view that will appear above all navigation bars in the app, why not use a Container View?

Make the Container View fill the screen, but give it a 20 point top margin to fit your custom green view. Then when you add your main view controller (wrapped in a navigation view controller) to the Container View, it will show your green view above it.

If you don't want your margin in a particular screen, do the following:
Add a constraint to the top margin and add an outlet to it so you can modify the constraint's constant in code.
Then, in any screens where you don't need the margin, access the parent view controller view and set the constraint's constant to zero.

```
let myParentViewController = self.parentViewController as? MyParentViewController
myParentViewController.myTopMarginLayoutConstraint.constant = 0
```

Don't forget to reset it to 20 (or whatever) when you go to a screen where you need the top margin again.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot thank you. What would you recommend to do if there are instances where I would not want the view to appear ?